# Instantiating objects with C# delegates

Tags: c#

I stumbled across the `DoStuffOneWay`, and it has me a bit confused. What is the functional difference in these two approaches below? It seems to be quite popular to use the delegate method, but to me it appears a bit verbose?

And options are modified *in place*? What? And it prevents you from passing an object through multiple layers?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoStuffOneWay(o =>
            {
                o.Foo = "foo";
                o.Bar = "bar";
            });

            DoStuffOtherWay(new Options()
            {
                Foo = "foo",
                Bar = "bar"
            });
        }

        private static void DoStuffOneWay(Action<Options> configOptions)
        {
            var options = new Options();

            configOptions(options);

            Console.WriteLine(options);
        }

        private static void DoStuffOtherWay(Options configOptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(options);
        }
    }

    public class Options
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: The delegate / lambda method allows for dynamic reloading. If you pass an object, the receiving function can only use that object. If you pass a "factory method", it can re-evaluateit whenever it wants. (or later, which allow for lazy-loading). In the case you show, that makes not much difference of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common pattern in the options/config space. Both methods have some advantage and disadvantage

- `DoStuffOneWay`: passing a delegate allows the underlying system to instantiate the actual object however it likes, it also allows the underlying system to apply your options repeatedly
- `DoStuffOtherWay`: Allows you to pass your options object from whichever system you like, and fully control the lifecycle of these objects.

Answer (score 1):

In your `DoStuffOneWay` you are passing a delegate - it holds a method reference. This `Action<Options> configOptions` is converted to a method by the C# compiler. So basically you are passing a method in to your `DoStuffOneWay` method.

On the other hand in your `DoStuffOtherWay`, you pass `Options` type parameter in to that method. Its just a method parameter.

That was the difference between two. Basically two approaches are for two different purposes